# C# Can't get this json deserialized

Tags: c#, arrays, json, deserialization

I've been trying to deserialize an array of objects in C# with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>().

I don't know how to do it.

I tried with List ListFotos = JsonConvert...
I tried  to modify my Fotos object adding a List and a List<Dictionary<object, string>>

Help me please.

JSON:

```
{
      "error": {
        "id": 0,
        "msg": "OK"
      },
      "parte": {
        "datos": {
          "id_parte": "",
          "titulo": "",
          "hotel": "",
          "bloque": "",
          "planta": "",
          "habitacion": "",
          "tipo": "",
          "fechacreacion": "",
          "creador": "",
          "departamentocreador": ""
        },
        "fotos": [
          {
            "id_foto": "3574",
            "archivo": "2021060411202834031400.jpg"
          },
          {
            "id_foto": "3575",
            "archivo": "2021060411203492625800.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "historico": [
          {
            "fechaevento": "",
            "estado": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "usuarioasignado": "",
            "proveedor": "",
            "tipoterceros": "",
            "fechaaplazado": ""
          },
          {
            "fechaevento": "",
            "estado": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "usuarioasignado": "",
            "proveedor": "",
            "tipoterceros": "",
            "fechaaplazado": ""
          },
          {
            "fechaevento": "",
            "estado": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "usuarioasignado": "",
            "proveedor": "",
            "tipoterceros": "",
            "fechaaplazado": ""
          },
          {
            "fechaevento": "",
            "estado": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "usuarioasignado": "",
            "proveedor": "",
            "tipoterceros": "",
            "fechaaplazado": ""
          },
          {
            "fechaevento": "",
            "estado": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "usuarioasignado": "",
            "proveedor": "",
            "tipoterceros": "",
            "fechaaplazado": ""
          },
          {
            "fechaevento": "",
            "estado": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "usuarioasignado": "",
            "proveedor": "",
            "tipoterceros": "",
            "fechaaplazado": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

C#:

```
...
if (item.Key.ToString() == "fotos")
{
    parte_fotos = item.Value.ToString();
    List<Model.Fotos> fotos = await App.Database.GetFotosAsync();
    Model.Fotos foto = new Model.Fotos();
    foto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Fotos>(parte_fotos);
    foto.ID_Parte = id;
}
...
```

The error i have:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'WorkersApp.Model.Fotos' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureArrayContract (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract) [0x00058] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.Object existingValue, System.String id) [0x00012] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x0007f] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader r06-22 12:56:32.085 V/mono-stdout(31636):   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00054] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x0002d] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value) [0x00000] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at 06-22 12:56:32.086 V/mono-stdout(31636):   at WorkersApp.Pageviews.Partes.GetDatosParteFromApi (System.String url, System.String id) [0x0066c] in C:\Users\CGarcia\source\repos\WorkersApp\WorkersApp\WorkersApp\Pageviews\Partes.xaml.cs:155
```

The error hits on this line:

```
foto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Fotos>(parte_fotos);
```

EDIT:

I have been asked to post:

string parte_fotos contains:

```
"[\n  {\n    \"id_foto\": \"3566\",\n    \"archivo\": \"2021060312461958641800.jpg\"\n  }\n]"
```

and Model.Fotos code is:

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
namespace WorkersApp.Model
{
    public class Fotos
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string ID_Foto { get; set; }
        public string ID_Parte { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public string Archivo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual string being assigned to `parte_fotos`, anc what is your code for `Model.Fotos`?

Comment: @LukeStorry Sorry, i forgot to add that. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
foto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Fotos>>(parte_fotos);
```

Comment: Doing that it gives me error: CS0029: Cannot convert System.Collections.Generics.List<Model.Fotos> to Model.Fotos.

Comment: change how you declare your variable
you must be declaring it as `Model.Fotos foto;` but the deserialization now returns a List of type Model.Fotos

Comment: I think I love you.

Comment: XDD you are welcome
up vote the answer if it worked

Comment: In case someone is reading. As @Massaynus said: I changed the way I declared "foto" from Model.Fotos foto... TO: List<Model.Fotos> FotoList = new List<Model.Fotos>().

Comment: Isn't this the reason `var` exists?

Comment: yes but for this case I thought it would be better to be verbose for Cristian to better understand the issue

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to incorrect conversion from JSON object to Fotos model, for solving that first you must cast your JSON object to model, then you fetch Fotos list from your model:

```
fotos = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(parte_fotos)).parte.fotos;
```

Model object shown below:

```
public class Model
{
    public Error error { get; set; }
    public Parte parte { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}

public class Parte
{
    public Datos datos { get; set; }
    public List<Foto> fotos { get; set; }
    public List<Historico> historico { get; set; }
}

public class Datos
{
    public string id_parte { get; set; }
    public string titulo { get; set; }
    public string hotel { get; set; }
    public string bloque { get; set; }
    public string planta { get; set; }
    public string habitacion { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public string fechacreacion { get; set; }
    public string creador { get; set; }
    public string departamentocreador { get; set; }
}

public class Foto
{
    public string id_foto { get; set; }
    public string archivo { get; set; }
}

public class Historico
{
    public string fechaevento { get; set; }
    public string estado { get; set; }
    public string observaciones { get; set; }
    public string usuarioasignado { get; set; }
    public string proveedor { get; set; }
    public string tipoterceros { get; set; }
    public string fechaaplazado { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is try https://json2csharp.com/
This site converts JSON documents to C# classes...

So the generated classes are:

```
public class Error
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}

public class Datos
{
    public string id_parte { get; set; }
    public string titulo { get; set; }
    public string hotel { get; set; }
    public string bloque { get; set; }
    public string planta { get; set; }
    public string habitacion { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public string fechacreacion { get; set; }
    public string creador { get; set; }
    public string departamentocreador { get; set; }
}

public class Foto
{
    public string id_foto { get; set; }
    public string archivo { get; set; }
}

public class Historico
{
    public string fechaevento { get; set; }
    public string estado { get; set; }
    public string observaciones { get; set; }
    public string usuarioasignado { get; set; }
    public string proveedor { get; set; }
    public string tipoterceros { get; set; }
    public string fechaaplazado { get; set; }
}

public class Parte
{
    public Datos datos { get; set; }
    public List<Foto> fotos { get; set; }
    public List<Historico> historico { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Error error { get; set; }
    public Parte parte { get; set; }
}
```

You can acces it through:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```